# Laravel - Check query execution after attach() and detach()

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

After I execute this

```
$shop->articles()->attach($article_id);
```

or this

```
$shop->articles()->detach($article_id);
```

how do I make sure they actually get executed? In the first case it returns void, but also it saves automatically so I cannot use the save function to check it. In the second case it returns int, but what does it represent?

Comment: it represents affected rows count

Comment: detach returns number of detached items.

Comment: thanks. so if it's exactly one the query is one. what about attach?

Comment: `attach` doesn't return anything. I believe it would throw an exception if the insert failed though, so you can assume it worked if there was no exception.

Comment: I thought about that, but some more strict checking would be preferred.

Comment: Well your options are pretty limited. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L1019-L1036

Comment: How about writing some tests...... check that the bahvior you are looking for is accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it with `try/catch` and `DB::transaction/commit/rollback`.

```
try{
    \DB::transaction(function() use($shop, $article_id) {
        $shop->articles()->attach($article_id);
    });

    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \DB::rollback();

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(collect($e->getMessage()));
}
```